Determine minimum and maximum probability given marginal probabilities
The following question came to my mind. Let's assume we have $n$ events $A_i$ with given probabilities $p_i$ and an event $B$ which happens when a certain given combination of events $A_i$ happen. Now what is the maximum (and similarly, minimum) probability for $B$?
More formally states. Let $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$. Let our sample space be the power set of $S$ i.e. $\Omega=P(S)$. The events are $A_i=\{s|s\in S\land i\in s\}$. Probabilities $p_i=Pr(A_i)$ are given and $B\subset \Omega$ is a given event. These do not uniquely determine the probability of $B$, i.e. $Pr(B)$. The question is, what is the maximum (and similarly, minimum) possible value for $Pr(B)$ given these constraints?
Let's take a more concrete example. Let $S=\{1,2\}$. Then $\Omega = \{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$, $A_i = \{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$, and $A_2 = \{\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$. The let's say $B = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$, i.e. the event $B$ happens when $A_1$ or $A_2$ happens. It should be easy to see that the minimum probability for $B$ is $\min(p_1,p_2)$ and the maximum probability is $\min(p_1+p_2,1)$. When $n$ is only 2 this isn't very difficult to work out but for larger cases it's more difficult. Is there come kind of general formula or algorithm for it?

Let me first formalize your problem.
Let $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We choose a random set $X$ from $S$ according to some law such that $\mathbb{P}(i\in X)=p_i\in[0,1]$ for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$.
Let $B\subseteq S$, $B=\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\}$, and we want to know the upper and lower bounds for $$z:=\mathbb P(B\in X).$$
Assume w.l.o.g. that $i_1=1,\dots,i_k=k$, i.e., $B=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$.
Claim 1. The maximum (achievable) bound for $z$ is $\max(p_1,\dots,p_k)$.
Proof.  Suppose w.l.o.g. that $p_1=\max(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k)$ is the largest.
Let $U$ be a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable. Then include $j\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ in $X$ if and only if $U\le p_j$ (how we choose to include or not $j\in\{k+1,\dots,n\}$ in $X$ does not play a role).
Then obviously for $i\le k$ we have $\mathbb P(i\in X)=p_i$, $\mathbb P(B\in X)=p_1$ (since if we include $1$ then we include all $i=2,3,\dots,k$). Also it's clear that $\mathbb P(B\in X)\le \max_{i\in B} \mathbb P(i\in B)=p_1$, so $p_1$ is indeed the largest you can get.
For the minimum, I have only a partial answer:
Claim 2. The minimum (achievable) bound for $z$ is $0$ if $p_1+p_2+\dots+p_k\le 1$.
Proof. Let $U$ be a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable. Then includide $j\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ in $X$ if and only if
$$
p_1+p_2+\dots+p_{j-1}\le U\le p_1+p_2+\dots+p_{j-1}+ p_j
$$
(how we choose to include or not $j\in\{k+1,\dots,n\}$ in $X$ does not play a role).
Then obviously for $i\le k$ we have $\mathbb P(i\in X)=p_i$, while at the same time
$$
\mathbb P(i\in X\cap j\in X)=0\text{ for all }i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}, \ i\ne j
$$
yielding $\mathbb P(B\in X)=0$.

I think you misunderstood slightly. $B$ isn't a subset of $S$ but rather a subset of the power set of $S$ which is the sample space here.

I hope it's not too confusing that I had to use both power set and probability in my question. I marked the former with $P()$ and the latter with $Pr()$. Maybe some other notation would be clearer but I don't know what.

This doesn't really answer my question because of the aforementioned misunderstanding.
